# Issue with Doctrine OneToMany relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an issue with the doctrine relationship. I try different ways but anything won't work.
Idea is that I have a News entity and every news should have many comments. So I try next:

The News entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\ORM\Entity\NewsComment", mappedBy="news")
 */
protected \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $comments;

/**
 * News constructor.
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And NewsComment entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\ORM\Entity\News", inversedBy="comments")
 */
protected \App\ORM\Entity\News $news;
```

Every entity has its own get and set methods as well.

But, when I receive a News entity a can get comments collection but it always empty. On the other hand, I can take any NewsComment entity and get from this News entity. It is working fine. But not to another way.

Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Code seems fine. How can you tell that is the collection is empty? Are you sure you’re not seeing a lazy uninitialized collection?

Comment: @AlessandroChitolina Hello!. I try to show what I mean: https://prnt.sc/tw72nx

Comment: @AlessandroChitolina Hello again. Thank you. Everything works fine, the collection just a lazy load :) I'm a newbie in doctrine and I did not know this feature.
Now everything works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine sets owned (non-inversed) collection as lazy by default.
When retrieving an entity by database, you should see an empty `PersistentCollection` instead of `ArrayCollection`, with `initialized` property set to false.

When calling any method on that collection, doctrine fires the queries needed to initialize the collection and populate it.

Collection emptiness should be only checked invoking `isEmpty`.